# How do I activate PulseAudio when only being logged in via ssh?

Tags: sound, ssh, pulseaudio

I am using a console-based music player, called cmus. It is in the repositories.

If I ssh into my desktop computer from, say, a laptop and start cmus, I would like to be able to play music. But, if I'm not logged in via GDM on the desktop computer, pulseaudio doesn't seem to want to play sound. When I login via GDM on the desktop computer and start cmus through ssh, I do get sound.

*My question is:* Can I work around this somehow? Can I tell pulseaudio to be active even though I am not physically logged on the actual machine, but only remotely?

Thanks for any and all help!

Note: I am not trying to tunnel the sound *through* ssh. I instead want to enable the sound to come out of the speakers of the computer I ssh *into*. Please note the difference. If all of this is unclear, please let me know and I'll try my best to clarify!

Comment: Have you tried `pulseaudio --start`?

Comment: I have now, and that didn't work. `pulseaudio -v --check` produces:
"I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon running as PID 2125", but there is still no sound in the speakers until I log in via GDM, or via a VT.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a year old, but I figured this out myself just moments ago.

I have a machine (music@jukebox) and I discovered as long as I am logged in as the user music on the server I can log in simultaneously through ssh/putty/whatever on another machine and the audio plays through the speakers on the server machine just fine.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't help. The question was: "Can I tell pulseaudio to be active **even though I am not physically logged on the actual machine, but only remotely**?" Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found to do this so far is to run the audio program as root or with sudo.  I'm still looking for a better way.